# Page Route with new file dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How to use `MaterialPageRoute` with a new file dart?

My codes:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hello_world/settings_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(Belajar());

class Belajar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: Icon(Icons.android),
          title: Text('Hello World'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return SettingsPage();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**settings_page.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried the code above. But, give me an error:

```
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
```

What wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing just one thing

```
MaterialApp(
 home:Builder(
  //use this context to push new route
  builder:(context){
   return Scaffold(
    appBar://..
   );
  }
 )
)
```

here builder will introduce a new context which will contain the navigator introduced by material app

Comment: accepting the answer will help others in future

Answer (score -1):

First create a class for example `runFunction()`

and you can use these code for going to that screen

```
Navigator.push(

              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => runFunction(),
              ),

            );
```

an example of runFuction

```
class _recipeSearchState extends State<recipeSearch> {

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('hello'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Text"),
          
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```